# C# syntax - Colon after a variable name

Tags: c#, syntax, .net-4.0

Quick question; I've recently upgraded to VS2010, and got the new version of ReSharper.

Now, when ReSharper is giving me autocomplete options for a variable, it give me the option of <*variableName*>:

What does the **:** stand for?

For example; I have this:

```
var productIds = new List<int>(inventoryItemsToProcess.Keys);
```

And when I start typing out a line like this:

```
var lastOrderDates = GetProductLastOrderDates(pro
```

It gives me the option for `productIds` as well as `productIds:`

What's the difference between the two?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The second is for C# 4.0 [named arguments](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2008/11/01/c-4-0-feature-focus-part-2-named-parameters.aspx). And here's a [link on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx).

Comment: More accurately, named arguments. Parameters have always had names :)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: dude, you do realize you're the only guy that knows the difference between parameters and arguments right? ;-)

Comment: @Kris, simple, complete and correct questions always get simple, complete and correct answers :-)

Comment: @Kris: I'm hoping that eventually the rest of the world will care :)

Comment: Interesting feature. Just like in Swift. Thanks

Comment: In javascript parameters don't always have names... **breathes heavily: ((arguments))**

Answer (score 52):

The colon is necessary to indicate parameters.  In C# 4.0, you can re-order and name your parameters, optionally, but the variable name must match the prototype and have the colon postfix.

```
public void Test(string something1, string something2)
{
}
```

can be called as:

```
Test(something2: "bar", something1: "foo");
```

if you want

Comment: Thanks for providing an illustration, not just a link.